# Karate - How to import json data

Tags: json, unit-testing, karate

I want to import some JSON data to my tests.
In order to documentation I should do that like this:

```
* def data = read('classpath:init/data.json')
```

I've created my JSON file with this content:

```
{
    "name": "ehsan"
}
```

This is my code:

```
  Background:
    * def data = call read('classpath:init/data.json')

  Scenario:
    * print data
```

But it prints nothing and says:

```
16:11:30.898 [main] WARN com.intuit.karate - not a js function or feature file: read('classpath:init/data.json') - [type: JSON, value: com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext@7d61eccf]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below code is correct:

```
* def data = read('classpath:init/data.json')
```

Only you must remove [call]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, read the error message (and the doc) carefully - there is no meaning in 'calling' a JSON file, the moment you `read` it - you have your re-usable data already. Just do this:

```
Background:
    * def data = read('classpath:init/data.json')

  Scenario:
    * print data
```

Comment: Please another question in this context :

How to import all javascript files that we have in the project?

Comment: @YounessMourtaji that will never be supported

Comment: So we need to import each javascript needed in a variable in order to use it?

Comment: @YounessMourtaji correct, otherwise there would be maintenance issues. you can always write a small utility that does it for your project if you really want this kind of thing. all the best