# Is it possible to have two baseUrls in the karate-config.js?

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where I will be doing the integration test with other product. So I have two URLs and each has separate Authorization Token. Is it possible to have two baseUrls in karate-config.js and if yes how can we have access them in the feature file?

```
karate-config.js

if(env == 'pre-prod')
{
     config.baseUrl='url1'
}

headers.js

function() {    
  var authheaders = {};
  switch(baseUrl){
      case 'url1':authheaders = { Authorization: 'auth-token'}
                  break;
                 }
                 return authheaders
                 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make the following changes in
the karate-config.js file like below,

```
function() {
  var env = karate.env; // get java system property 'karate.env'
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
  if (!env) {
    env = 'local'; // a custom 'intelligent' default
  }
  var config = { // base config
    env: env,
    profile: 'local',
    DataSetUrl: 'http://localhost:9005/v0.2.4/',
    DMUrl: 'http://localhost:8004/v0.2.3/',
    SchemaUrl: 'http://localhost:8006/v0.2.3/',
    URUrl: 'http://localhost:9005/v0.2.4/',
    username: 'null', 
    password: 'null'
  };
  if (env == 'staging') {
    // over-ride only those that need to be
    var config = { // base config
            env: env,
            profile: 'staging',
            baseUrl: 'staging url',
            dbname: 'url2',
            server_url: '12.12.12.12',
            server_port: 31700,
            username: 'mongo-staging-user', 
            dbname: 'db_name',
            password: 'passoword'
          };    
  } 
  }
  // don't waste time waiting for a connection or if servers don't respond
    // within 5 seconds
  karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
  karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
  return config;
}
```

For the Authorisation you can create a config.feature file which will look like this,

```
Feature: Auth

  Scenario: Auth
    * def Auth = 'auth'
```

And in the feature file you can use the urls and authorization

```
Feature: Test 

Background: 
    * def config = call read('classpath:features/Config.feature')
    * def auth = config.Auth

Scenario:1

* url DMUrl
Given path 'yourpath'
When method get
Then status 200
#
* url DataSetUrl
Given path 'yourpath'
When method get
Then status 200
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the best way would be prefix with your app-name,

```
if (env == 'pre-prod') {
    config.AppOne = {
        baseUrl: 'url1',
        getHeader: function() {
            return {
                Authorization: 'App one token'
            };
        }
    };
    config.AppTwo = {
        baseUrl: 'url2',
        getHeader: function() {
            return {
                Authorization: 'App two token'
            };
        };
    }
}
```

while using in feature use

```
* url AppOne.baseUrl
* path 'apiOne/endpoint'
* headers AppOne.getHeader()
# <other steps for App One>
* url AppTwo.baseUrl
* path 'apiTwo/endpoint'
* headers AppOne.getHeader()
# <other steps for App Two>
```

This way you can have a global configuration for more than one application at a time.

Comment: also see this for other ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49693808/143475

Comment: @Babu Sekaran I am using path instead of URL. How can that be resolved? eg: Given path '/api-endpoint'

Comment: `url` is a mandatory parameter for making any rest call. You cannot simply pass `path` alone. You can even pass the entire endpoint in `url` as well.