# Karate integration with type config

Tags: api, automated-tests, karate

can we use any config framework like type config for java in karate? it can be used to pick up the values of keys mentioned in configuration file as per requirement.we have been using rest assured and type config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One word of advice is you need to un-learn a lot of "Java things" when you start with Karate. There is no need for type-config. Please see the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configuration

Also see this example for a example of "picking up keys" like you say: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49693808/143475

If you have a specific need, please ask a new question, and provide good examples. Anything is possible in Karate.