# How to execute same features in multiple environments in a single run in karate

Tags: karate

I have five different URL end-points(environments) for production and for QA and I need to execute the same features in all these production environments in a single run and get the result in one cucumber report- (In TestNG I was passing each environment as the parameter in separate XML file and then use a common TESTNG.XML file that contains all these XML,s with different environments).

How can I manage this in Karate-config file?

I have below production environments ProdV1,ProdV2,ProdV3 and ProdV4.

```html
    {
   "prod":{
      "endpoint_urls":{
         "ProdV1":"https://production1.com/prod/ProdV1",
         "ProdV2":"https://production2.com/prod/ProdV2"
         "ProdV3":"https://production.com/prod/ProdV3",
         "ProdV4":"https://production.com/prod/ProdV4"
      }
   },
   "uat":{
      "endpoint_urls":{
         "UatV1":"https://uat.abc.com/uat1/home-sec-uri",
         "Uatv2":"https://uat.abc.com/uat2/home-res-uri"
      }
   }
}
```

Using command line I know we can run a single environment by  command
'mvn clean -Dtest=TestRunner -DCucumber.Options="--tags "
DProvEnv=**ProdV1** '. But my question is how to run on all these production environments ProdV1, ProdV2,ProdV3 and ProdV4 together in a single run. Do we need to use for-loop? or is there any way other than that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running them all the time this is just data-driven testing: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests

Or there are many ways to loop over a data-set: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

If you ever want flexibility to not run some of them, use tags: https://github.com/intuit/karate#tags

Finally there are options where you can manage the data-set to loop in `karate-config.js`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49693808/143475

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question. In production itself I have 4 environments and I need to run on all these environments in a single run .How to run on all these production environments ProdV1, ProdV2,ProdV3 and ProdV4 together in a single run. Do we need to use for-loop? or is there any way other than that?

Comment: @Sumith you call it an "environment" but to me it is just a JSON file with 4 values that you use to do data-driven testing, now go and re-read the links I posted.

Comment: Sorry I tried but I was not able to get it. I saw how to call other feature with a json array but my requirement is, I have 12 feature file all using   Background: * url urlendpoint, where 'urlendpoint' is sent from karate config. I need to first execute all that 12 features with one environment url -ProdV1. then again the execute that 12 feature with with other url -ProdV1 on a loop .

Comment: @Sumith I think I have done my best to give you a solution, if you read the links. I am giving up, over to other Karate users who might help you