# reuse karate tests from other feature file by passing in params

Tags: karate

We have a set of services that all expose certain common endpoints such as a health check, version information etc. I am trying to use karate to write smoke tests for these multiple services in a reusable way that i can just pass in the service name and endpoint and have the tests executed for each service.

basicChecks.feature

```
Feature: Smoke Test. verify health check and version and index are ok

  Scenario: Verify that test server health check is up and running
    Given url '#(baseUrl)'

    Given path '/health'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match response == "'#(name)' ok"

    Given path '/version'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match response contains {'#(name)'}
```

testServices.feature

```
Feature: Smoke Test for services.

  Scenario: Verify that test server health check is up and running

    * call read('basic.feature') { name: 'service1' , baseUrl : service1Url }
    * call read('basic.feature') { name: 'service2' , baseUrl : service2Url }
```

karate-config.js

```
function fn() {
  var env = karate.env; // get java system property 'karate.env'
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
  if (!env) {
    env = 'local'; // a custom 'intelligent' default
  }
  var config = { // base config JSON
    appId: 'my.app.id',
    appSecret: 'my.secret',
    service1Url: 'https://myserver/service1'
    service2Url: 'https://myserver/service2'
  };
 
  // don't waste time waiting for a connection or if servers don't respond within 5 seconds
  karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
  karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
  return config;
}
```

When i run this i get an error suggesting that the baseUrl is not being picked up when passed in

```
20:27:22.277 karate.org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified, http call failed after 442 milliseconds for url: /health#(baseUrl) 20:27:22.278 cas/src/test/java/karate/smoke/basic.feature:7 When method get http call failed after 442 milliseconds for url: /health#(baseUrl) cas/src/test/java/karate/smoke/basic.feature:7
```

I looked at https://intuit.github.io/karate/#code-reuse--common-routines but could not figure out how to use the same tests but pass in different endpoints?

Or maybe since i am totally new to karate there is a much better way of doing this than what i have outlined?

Thank you for your time.

Edit - I am trying to test different micro services in the same environment and not trying to switch different environments etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the recommended approach. When you have different URL-s for different environments, you should switch environments using the approach in the documentation (setting `karate.env`) and NOT depend on re-use via "call" etc.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49693808/143475

And if you really want you can run suites one after the other switching the `karate.env`, although that is rare.

Or if you just trying "data" driven testing, there are plenty of ways, just [read the docs](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests) and search Stack Overflow for `Scenario Outline`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bkarate%5d%20Scenario%20Outline

If you are trying to do this "clever" re-use using "call" I strongly recommend that you don't and please read this for why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

EDIT - I think you ran into this problem, read the docs please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Comment: These are different micro services in the same environment only.

Comment: @Gokul I think you ran into this specific problem with embedded expressions, read this please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions