# Pass url to feature file from json file

Tags: javascript, json, cucumber, karate

I am trying to pass a url to karate.feature from json file. I never get to extract the url in feature file.

Below is my code example based on [Pass Json to karate-config.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690975/pass-json-to-karate-config-js-file).

I have also tried this stackoverflow answer Karate - [How to import json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035817/karate-how-to-import-json-data/47041833#47041833) by [Peter Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143475/peter-thomas)

#### env-data.json

```
{
   "dev":{
      "url":{
         "uri1":"https://example.com/dev/uri1/",
         "uri2":"https://example.com/dev/uri2/"
      }
   },
   "qa":{
      "url":{
         "uri1":"https://example.com/qa/uri1/",
         "uri2":"https://example.com/qa/uri2/"
      }
   }
}
```

#### karate-config.js

```
 function() {
  var env = 'dev'; // karate.env
  var temp = read('classpath:env-data.json');
  return temp[env];
}
```

#### karate.feature

```
Scenario: Testing that GET response contains specific field
Given url url['uri1']
Given path 'check'
When method GET
Then status 200
And match $ == {#notnull}
```

#### testRunner.java

```
@RunWith(Karate.class)
public class testRunner {    
}
```

#### Command I am using:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=testRunner -Dkarate.env=dev
```

when I run the tests, `Given url url['uri1']` this step from feature file couldn't able to retrieve the url from json file. Not sure what I am missing. Please help me.

Comment: the best way for you to get ANY help is to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Please post the step definition, otherwise we can't help you.